# If I want to auto-charge users when they use the service

Tags: paypal

Right now I am making a website that will charge service buyers' money after the service with paypal, Will I be able to do it?

I know that most of the time website that use paypal to process money will need the buyer to perform the paying action. I am in question if there is way that my website can use paypal as a money processor to charge buyers money without they have to perform any action, kind of like those recurring payment that buyer do not need to bother to do the paying procedure again and again. We would like the website to charge them whenever they use the service, and they will be notified that money is charged after they have the service.

Can paypal money processor do that? or there is some other better way?

Thanks